# Get list of child class from list of parent class

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public String Name{get; set;}
    public Bar BarValue {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Value{get; set;}
}
```

Also I have a `List<Foo>`. How can I get `List<Bar>` from `List<Foo>`?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. Your first part (about 2 classes) doesn't look connected with your second part (about the lists) and also the question itself is totally unclear.

Comment: @YakovL Wow, I haven't seen that. SO editor hide words in such braces '< >'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completly sure I understood your question but if I did then:

*From what I understand you have a list of `Foo`s and you want all the `Bar` objects that are in those `Foo`s. Right?*

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();    
List<Bar> bars = foos.Select(foo => foo.BarValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't have a reference to Linq Extension Methods (`using system.linq;`) you can still do it the classical way:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();

foreach (Foo f in foos)
{
    bars.Add(f.BarValue);
}
```

Or (After adding `using system.linq;` at the top of your file):

```
List<Bar> bars = foos.Select(f => f.BarValue).ToList();
```